# Erro nas functions sqlsrv_query e sqlsrv_num_rows()

Tags: php, sql-server

Boa tarde, não tenho muita experiencia em php estou começando agora com essa linguagem e estou com um problema com duas functions segue print do problema:

> Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bolean given in ... daoLogin.php on line 17
>
> Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
>   in ... daoLogin on line 19

e o código:

```
<?php

  $server = "Filipe-PC\SQLExpress";
  $database = "bd_CaminhoVerde";
  $user = "caminho_verde";
  $pass = "greenway";

  $infoConexao = array("Database" => $database, "UID" => $user, "PWD" => $pass);
  $conectar = sqlsrv_connect($server, $infoConexao);

  $usuario = $_POST['txtUsuario'];
  $senha = $_POST['txtSenha'];

  $queryLogar = "execute usp_logar @usuario = ?, @senha = ?";
  $parameter = array($usuario, $senha);

  $query_Resultado = sqlsrv_query($conectar, $queryLogar, $parameter);

  if(sqlsrv_num_rows($query_Resultado) > 0)
  {
    session_start();

    $array_Resultado = mssql_fetch_array($query_Resultado);
    $_SESSION['cpf'] = $array_Resultado['cpf'];
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $array_Resultado['nome'];
    $_SESSION['creditos'] = $array_Resultado['creditos'];
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $array_Resultado['usuario'];

    header("Location:home.php");
  }
  else{ }

 ?>
```

Agradeço a atenção desde já

Obs: ja extrai os drivers do php_sqlsrv_56_ts e php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts e da referenciei no php.ini

Array de erro com sql-server:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados n�o encontrado e nenhum driver padr�o especificado [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados n�o encontrado e nenhum driver padr�o especificado ) )
```

Comment: vc rodar essa sp direto no banco? o erro diz apenas que deu falha na consulta.

Comment: no banco a sp ta rodando de boa, sem erro nenhum

Comment: Com esse usuário e senha vc consegue rodar outras consultas pelo php? para que `$conectar` recebeu false, logo a conexão não foi feita.

Comment: Eu fiz outro código pra testar a conexão como você disse e encontrei a array de erro com sql, vou coloca-la no final da pergunta

Comment: Instala o ODBC aí que deve resolver.

Comment: Sim eu instalei ontem e arrumou, tipo eu desinstalei varias vezes os drivers de php pq o links de solução da microsoft me levavam sempre a novos drivers e era problema com ODBC

Comment: vlw ai pela ajuda